# Can I use a soft switching IGBT (FGA 25n120: given in specification) for my variable frequency drive power circuit (frequency around 10-20kHz)?

Tags: power-electronics, switching, induction-motor, igbt

I am building a variable frequency drive from scratch. The design worked well with switching MOSFET. Now I need to increase the power output and DC bus voltage so that I would like to implement FGA25N120 into my circuit. But the datasheet says it is a soft switching IGBT designed for resonant circuits. Should I use it with my hard switching circuit? Which are the best switching IGBT models I can choose  for 1KW motor driver?

Comment: can you show the schematic?

Comment: Haven't yet developed a pcb schematic. Now working with dotted pcbs. I am using TLP250 as the gate driver(6 of them for 6 switches)